Ubuntu desktop 20.04 LTS security
I have download Ubuntu desktop version 20.40 LTS Iso image using windows 10 os from official Ubuntu.com web site. Not sure windows 10 had trustable security. My dell Inspiron 3050 Laptop has no DVD drive. I downloaded Rufus 4.5 and created bootable USB pen and install Ubuntu.
Then configure Apache2, mysql and phpmyadmin using sudo commands.  I configure my personally developed student management system (PHP, mysql, html, css, JavaScript) and try to access via localhost using Firefox.
When logged in and try to view administrator details Firefox ask to save the email and password of first record of administrators table. I am wondering how Firefox get that data as user email and password. I log using other account. I don't type that user email and password any time any where.
How did firefox get my user email and password?

Did you sign in to Firefox? That may sync the frequently used emails and saved passwords.

You didn't type it in, but phpmyadmin might have loaded that table and put into editable HTML fields whose names would contain something like username and password, right? That could be enough to confuse Firefox's detection of login forms.

@muru Thanks a lot. I think that's the reason. I use same name email, password in bath database table and html form. Html form is not a login form. But update user data form. Also phpmyadmin view data as inline editable format. I developed this system in 2012. Now back to work again. I think it is compulsory to encrypt passwords using one-way algorythams. Am I right?
